# adding 1 to variable each time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am creating (the user pressing a button) many UIImageViews programmly, and assigning a tag to each when created in this way:

```
    int a;

    if (a != nil){

        a = 0;
    }

    a = a + 1;
    image1.tag = a;
```

the problem is that with a = a +1 I would like the variable to increase: 1,2,3,4... but it remains always 1, so each Image has a tag of 1. if I add a++, the tag 2 is assigned to all. why?? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming a is a simple type.

Firstly you should never compare a simple type like so;

```
if (a != nil){
    a = 0;
}
```

However, the if statement above will always be true after the first button is pressed because a will be > 0 and therefore will not evaluate to NULL.  So your if statement will always reset a back to zero.  If you want the tag to increment remove that if statement.

Assuming a is not a simple type.

Make a an int and also remove the if statement.  Heres is some supporting code.

`@implementation ViewController{
    int a;
}
-(void)pressed{
    a = a + 1;
    NSLog(@"%d",a);
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    a = 0;
    UIButton * b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
}
@end`

Comment: thanks, works fine, apart from the NSLog(@"%d",a); which does not display anything.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming `a` is an `int` or some other primitive type. A primitive type will **never** be `nil` (okay so yes, `nil` is technically `(void *)0`, but lets not even go there. You shouldn't use `nil` for primitive types.); only an object can be `nil`. Therefore,

```
if (a != nil)
```

Will **always** be true unless `a` is zero and thus, `a` will be set back to zero every time.

Edit: You're also declaring `a` within the scope of your method call, so it's going to get re-created every time. Move it to a synthesized property.

Comment: `a != 0` but also, you shouldn't be defining A within the scope of it's increment, `int a;` is going to reset it back to (void *)0 each time.  (Unless that declaration for the variable `a` is just for clarification purposes here).

Comment: how can I do this: "A within the scope of it's increment"

Comment: You need to move your declaration for `a` out of the function. Make it a synthesized property instead. In your header file, you need `@property (nonatomic) int a;` and in your implementation, `@synthesize a;`.

Answer (score 0):

`nil` is equal to 0. So at the beginning of the method, if `a` isn't 0, you set it to 0 and then increment it. Just kill the nil check altogether and it should work.